# Getting 'coordinates' of a csv list

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV file with values that can change and the file can be appended using a module I made. I want to make a module that can search whether a value is contained in the file and its location in the file.
What i have right now is:

```
import csv
def GET_ROW_COUNT():
    with open('battle_royale.csv', 'r') as source:
        battleRoyaleData = csv.reader(source, delimiter=',')
        row_count = sum(1 for row in battleRoyaleData)
    return row_count
def DISPLAY_PLAYERS():
    with open('battle_royale.csv', 'r') as source:
        battleRoyaleData = csv.reader(source, delimiter=',')
        for row in battleRoyaleData:
            print(row)
def WRITE_PLAYER(avatarName, name):
    csv_list = []
    rowCount = GET_ROW_COUNT()
    with open('battle_royale.csv', 'r') as source:
        battleRoyaleData = csv.reader(source, delimiter=',')
        for row in battleRoyaleData:
            csv_list.append(row)
        csv_list.append([f"'{avatarName}'", f"'{name}'", f"'{rowCount}'"])
    with open('battle_royale.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        newWrite = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        newWrite.writerows(csv_list)
```

I'm thinking I would use

```
data = []
    with open('battle_royale.csv', 'r') as source:
        battleRoyaleData = csv.reader(source, delimiter=',')
        for row in battleRoyaleData:
            row = [t for t in row] 
            data.append(row)
```

and then include like

```
if (value) in data:
    coordinates = #some way to get the position of the value in the list from index
```

----Edit----
How can I get the position of a value and know whether the value exists in a list?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read [tour] and [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, You trying to implement CRUD operations for csv files.

- Create
- Read
- Update
- Delete

For this purpose, you can use `sqlite3` database and simple SQL queries.
It won't be harder than your idea with csv.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html
It also has a nice client to interact with the data.
https://sqlitebrowser.org/